# open block on div click from list of div's in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="lsiting-main">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
    <span class="close-list">
    <span class="funded-list">
    <span class="new-list">
      <div class="technology closedlanguage" headerindex="0h">
          <span class="accordprefix"> </span>
             View Detail Notice
          <span class="accordsuffix"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="thelanguage" contentindex="0c" style="display: none;">
   <div align="center">
   <div class="big-listing-details">
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<div class="lsiting-main">
......
</div>
<div class="lsiting-main">
......
</div>
```

I have list of `class="listing-main"` and i try to open block `class="thelanguage" style="display: none;"` on click of `class="technology closedlanguage"`. 
But what i need, when i click on `class="technology closedlanguage"` at that time class change `"closedlanguage"` to `"openlanguage"` and style change `'none'` to `'block'`.

**But when i click, only one block open at that time from list of div's**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lsiting-main .closedlanguage').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $('.thelanguage');
        $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
        $('.thelanguage').css('display', 'block');
    })
});
```

Comment: Welcome @Roshan. You can use `$(selector).addClass(classToBeAdded).removeClass(classToBeRemoved)`. You can also try $.toggleClass(), or $.toggle()

Comment: Is the `thelanguage` block only one block? Or 1 every after each `lsiting-main` block?

Comment: "thelanguage" block is in every "lsiting-main" div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the HTML a bit and also if your willing to use JavaScript then refer the below code, it is working as per your expectation.

Here is the JSFiddle Link: [Working JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ys7nnphn/)

JS Code is :

```
 <script>
 document.getElementById("technologyclosedlanguage").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(){
            var thelanguage = document.getElementById("thelanguage");
            var technology =  document.getElementById("technologyclosedlanguage");     
            thelanguage.style.display="block";
            technology.className = "technologyopenlanguage";
            alert(technology.className); //class name changed.
}
</script>
```

HTML Code is :

```
    <div class="lsiting-main">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
    <span class="close-list">
    <span class="funded-list">
    <span class="new-list">
      <div class="technologyclosedlanguage" id="technologyclosedlanguage" headerindex="0h">
          <span class="accordprefix"> </span>
             View Detail Notice
          <span class="accordsuffix"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="thelanguage" id="thelanguage" contentindex="0c" style="display: none;">
   <div align="center">
   <div class="big-listing-details">
       The Language
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<div class="lsiting-main">
......
</div>
<div class="lsiting-main">
......
</div>
```

Let me know if it works, and helps you. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".closedlanguage").click(function (event) {
        var target = $(".thelanguage");
        $(target).toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".hidden").css("display", "none");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```